# Select employees belong to both department in database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table

```
 EmpName   DeptID
-------------------------
   Sam        1
   John       2
   Sam        2
   Bill       3
   Mary       1
```

I want to select employees who belong to both DeptID '1' and DeptID '2'
For this table i want to show EmpID : sam
How can i write a query in MySql

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach using `sum`

```
select EmpName
from demo
group by EmpName
having sum(DeptID = 1) 
and sum(DeptID = 2)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a283bb/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use `HAVING` with `GROUP BY`.

**Query**

```
select EmpName from your_table_name
where DeptID in (1,2)
group by EmpName 
having count(distinct DeptID) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an having clause   on the filterd  rows

```
  select empname 
  from my_table
  where dempId in (1,2)
  group by empname
  having count(distinct DeptID) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method using self join

```
Select empname
From table t1
Join table t2
Using (empname)
Where t1.deptid = 1
  And t2.deptid = 2
```